# batch remove audio from flv files

Tags: video, ffmpeg, flv

I have a batch of flv files, and i want to remove all the audio that is in the file. Is this possible? I have tried to use ffmpeg, but am not able to do it, can someone direct me in the right direction? is there a way using C or any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to completely *remove* the audio?  ffmpeg can do that, so in what way could you not use it?  Was it failing to work properly?

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -an output.flv
```

.. should do it (in fact, it does, I just tested it with ffmpeg 0.10.2 on SL6). So:

```
# in bash
for file in *.flv
do
    ffmpeg -i "$file" -an $(basename "$file" .flv)-edit.flv
done
```

.. will do all .flv files in the current directory, creating *-edit.flv versions (leaving the originals safe).

**Update**: you should probably also add the appropriate video-copy option as described by *LordNeckbeard* below.

Comment: You should add `-c:v copy` or `-vcodec copy` (same thing; different syntax for different ffmpeg versions) as an output option to copy the video streams instead of re-encoding.